# Inverting a block matrix: $B$, $C$, $D$, $O$ are matrices, not scalars

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A= $\begin{bmatrix}B & C\\0 & D\end{bmatrix}$ be block triangular matrix (here $B$, $C$, $D$, $0$ are matrices, not scalars). Show that:

a) $A$ is invertible iff $B$ and $D$ are invertible.

b)Find $A^{-1}$  provided $B^{-1}$ and $D^{-1}$ are known.

c)Make use of b) to invert the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 &-1 &-1\\-3& 1 &-3 &-3 \\ 0 &0&0&2\\ 0& 0& -1 & -3\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** look for an inverse matrix in the form
$\begin{bmatrix}B' & C'\\0 & D'\end{bmatrix}$.

This is justified because the left bottom part of the matrix is invariant in the process of the Gauss algorithm if it is already 0 at the start.

---

solution:
$$\begin{bmatrix}B' & C'\\0 & D'\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}B & C\\0 & D\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}I & 0\\0 & I\end{bmatrix}
\iff
BB' = I, DD' = I, B'C + C'D = 0
$$
then there is a solution iff  $D$ and $B$ are invertible.

In this case the solution is
$$
B' = B^{-1},\\
D' = D^{-1},\\
C' = - B^{-1}CD^{-1}
$$

Comment: @idAl: look at my edit for the solution.

Comment: Could you help me with part b) i found it but i am not quite sure @mookid... Is it [ B^-1 - B^-1* C* D^-1 ; 0 D^-1]??

Comment: please, it is in my answer. btw you did not either accept it or upvote it, did you at least read it?

Comment: Yes i am sorry i didn't notice it... I was trying to use it to solve part C but it was getting more complicated... How do i use it to find part c @mookid

Comment: Can't you inverse the 2x2 matrices and made the product?

Comment: also, do not forget to accept an answer if your question has been answered.

Comment: I reversed it by using the formula 1/(ad-cd)[d -b ;-c a] @mookid

Comment: yes, and you can check the result using wolfram alpha is needed, even if it should not be necessary for 2x2 example.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\begin{bmatrix}B & C\\0 & D\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I & 0\\0 & D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}B & C\\0 & I\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}B^{-1} & ?\\0 & D^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using block matrix determinant, you would get:
$$\det{A} = \det{B}\det{D}$$
and the conclusion follows.

Alternatively, you can find explicitly the inverse matrix of $A$ following Romdhane and mookid's hints. You will see that $B^{-1}$ and $D^{-1}$ would be blocks, so they need to be invertible.

By doing so, you would solve item b.

The third item is just a matter of computations...

Comment: if you could help me with another way it would be really helpful because determinant is a term which i have not taken yet @Victor